# How to make Sidebar row remember its previous detail view progress for split view SwiftUI Mac catalyst?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mac-catalyst, swiftui-navigationview, splitview

I am creating Split View with NavigationView in SwiftUI MacCatalyst. In sidebar (master view), I have two rows: 'Add' and 'Profile'. Tapping on them changes the detail view.

Suppose I click on 'Add' row, I see AddView() in detail view.
[image: First Tap]

Then I tap 'Next 1' button to show 'TempView 1' on navigation stack.
[image: Second Tap]

Now, I tap on 'Profile' row in sidebar.
[image: Third Tap]

And when I tap one 'Add' row in sidebar again, I see this:
[image: Fourth Tap]

instead of this:
[image: Second Tap]

Does anyone know how to preserve row stages for SplitView in SwiftUI? My sample code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddView: View {
    @State var showNext = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: TempView1(), isActive: $showNext) { EmptyView() }
                
                Button("Next 1") {
                    showNext = true
                }
                
                Text("Add View")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
    @State var showNext = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: TempView2(), isActive: $showNext) { EmptyView() }
                
                Button("Next 2") {
                    showNext = true
                }
                Text("Profile View")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct TempView1 : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Temp View 1")
    }
}

struct TempView2 : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Temp View 2")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showAddView = false
    @State var showProfileView = false
    @State var selectedRow = -1
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: AddView(), isActive: $showAddView) { EmptyView() }
                NavigationLink(destination: ProfileView(), isActive: $showProfileView) { EmptyView() }
                List {
                    Text("Add")
                        .padding()
                        .background(selectedRow == 0 ? Color.yellow : Color.clear)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedRow = 0
                            showAddView = true
                        }
                    Text("Profile")
                        .padding()
                        .background(selectedRow == 1 ? Color.yellow : Color.clear)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedRow = 1
                            showProfileView = true
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Scene storage or some other model with persistence

Comment: @loremipsum Thank a lot. SceneStorage was helpful. I will post here again if I encounter a complex situation where it is not enough.